# Problem-solving

Tags: reference-request, problem-solving

I just finished my second year as a mathematics student at university. At university, we learn about advanced mathematics and problems. However, I'm also interested in some problems that doesn't acquire deep results from mathematics or a certain theory to solve them.

Now I'm looking for a good guide to learn more about this type of problem-solving. I want some pdf or a book that gives some brief introduction to a problem solving technique and after that a large bunch of problems. I don't want these problems to be too easy but I also don't want them to be too hard so that I have to know much modern results in mathematics to understand them.

Does anyone of you knows such a guide at my level (university student)?

Comment: The [Putnam exams](http://amc.maa.org/a-activities/a7-problems/putnamindex.shtml) might interest you.

Comment: I forget if Polya's "How to Solve It" has problems, but it was the go-to recommendation for this sort of thing when I was young.

Comment: Maybe try - ''Mathematical circles''. Just take a look at problems from chapters like - invariants . I think it might be too easy for you?

Answer (score 3):

I like "The Art and Craft of Problem Solving" by Paul Zeitz

Answer (score 2):

Problem-Solving Strategies

Arthur Engel

[http://www.amazon.com/Problem-Solving-Strategies-Problem-Books-Mathematics/dp/0387982191](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387982191)

Comment: I was going to recommend the same book.

Answer (score -1):

I have just the thing for you: "The Top-Down Approach to Problem Solving", by Eduardo Corpeño (yours truly), ISBN 979-8464073296. You can find it on amazon as paperback and ebook.
I hope it helps.