# How do you solve all exercise problems from a book if they are hard to do

Tags: commutative-algebra, self-learning, advice

I am reading Atiyah MacDonald's Introduction to Commutative Algebra book. Now I am enjoying reading the book but when I am doing the exercises I feel it is hard to do. In 20 problems almost 5-6 I can do on my own but for the rest, I have to take hints from solution. Even I have to actually read the whole solution for some problems. Now I feel like I am not learning anything like this.

How do you guys deal with such cases

Comment: That's a terse, difficult text.  The subject matter largely lives in the exercises.  Other texts might seem friendlier.

Comment: This is a great book, but definitely not one designed for self-study. How to deal with this? Well, what you have done by airing your problems on MSE is a good start. It might also be useful to think about what your goals are? Do you just want a beginner's introduction to ring theory or are you preparing to take on homological algebra or algebraic geometry or what?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem-solving](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428578/problem-solving)

Comment: @RobArthan I am planning to learn Algebraic Geometry. Thats why i am learning commutative algebra now. And i have done ring theory from artin and some parts from dummit foote

Comment: You might do better to find a good text on Algebraic Geometry (e.g., Hartshorne) and work backwards to the Commutatve Algebra results you need. But that's just a personal opinion as I know many people like to learn from the bottom up.

Comment: You can ask for help in the internet, hire a tutor that helps you, find another book that is easier. Also, it would be nice to find out why do really want to do all the exercises in a specific book. Specifically, how much does the learning process of algebraic geometry slow down when faced with a problem you don't know how to solve?